# Как посчитать количество разных символов в строке?

Tags: javascript

Есть строка.

> Ух. Привет, как твои дела?!

Мне нужно посчитать количество определенных символов.
Это конечно пример, пожалуйста подскажите скрипт на JS (необходимые символы - . , : ; !)

Comment: Mr. Music, если вас мой ответ удовлетворил, то поставьте галочку рядом с ответом слева, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

```
("Ух. Привет, как твои дела?!".split(/[.\,\?]/).length - 1);
```

что-то вроде этого.

Comment: Спасибо, верно. Только в конце еще "length - 1"

Comment: как посчитать тоже самое на php?

Comment: Экранивание не нужно (точку ведь не экранировали), т.к. эти специальные символы внутри `[]`: `/[.,?]/`

Comment: Слишком избирательно. Да в задаче конечно дана конкретная строка, но так же и даны конкретные символы (при чем там нет знака вопроса), по этому в регулярном выражении стоит и их указать, а не только те которые присутствуют в данной строке. Группировка тоже не очень показательный подход для ответа, если код не в виджете и нельзя посмотреть что он делает и как используется, лучше присвоить переменной, так как это очевиднее.

Comment: Ну и да, `match` как-то более подходящий метод, ибо нам надо посчитать кол-во вхождений.

Comment: Для php это будет что-то типа `preg_match_all('/[-.,:;!]/', 'Ух. Привет, как твои дела?!')`

Comment: @MedvedevDev в вопросе попросили показать пример и я указал знаки из строки. Конечно есть варианты и лучше, но это самый примитивный и легкий какой я знаю.

Answer (score 1):

возможно не очень красиво, зато не надо разбираться с регулярками

```js
function isFound(target, arr) {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (target == arr[i]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
function symbolsCount(symbolss, str) {
    let arr = str.split('');
    let count = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (isFound(arr[i], symbolss)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
let symbols = ['.', ',', ':', ';', '!'];
let str = 'Ух. Привет, как твои дела?!';
console.log(symbolsCount(symbols, str));
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так правильно:

```js
console.log("Ух. Привет, как твои дела?!".split(/[.,?!]/).length - 1);
```

**Смотрите также:**

[Создание регулярных выражений](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Answer (score 0):

Обычный парсер циклом

```js
var str = "Ух. Привет, как твои дела?!"
var length = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
{
  if (str[i] == '.' || str[i] == ',' || str[i] == '?' || str[i] == '!')
  {
    length++;
  }
}
console.log(length);
```

Либо можно создать массив ключей

```js
var str = "Ух. Привет, как твои дела?!"
var length = 0;
var keys = ['.' , ',' , '!', '?'];
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
{
  if (keys.indexOf(str[i]) != -1)
  {
    length++;
  }
}
console.log(length);
```